# How to determine if an Oracle deferrable constraint violation occurred in JPA?

Tags: oracle, jpa

Oracle 11g silently rolls back a transaction upon commit if the transaction has a deferred constraint violation.  One way to actually get an error is to set the constraint to *immediate* before calling commit.  This works fine using Oracle SQL Developer, but doing this in a JPA (EclipseLink) native query results in the application locking up.  Is there any alternative way to be notified if a deferred constraint was violated?  Or perhaps I'm not using JPA correctly?

Table definition:

```
create table foo
(
foo_id integer not null,
order_id integer not null,
constraint foo_pk primary key (foo_id),
constraint foo_ak unique (order_id) deferrable
);
```

SQL to generate violation and see error displayed on console:

```
set constraint foo_ak deferred;
insert into foo values (1, 1);
insert into foo values (2, 1);
set constraint foo_ak immediate; -- Will rollback and display error
```

JPA attempting to reorder a collection of foo entities in Stateless Session Bean:

```
public void edit(List<Foo> foos) {
    Query deferred = em.createNativeQuery("set constraint foo_ak deferred");
    Query immediate = em.createNativeQuery("set constraint foo_ak immediate");

    deferred.executeUpdate(); // This works

    for(Foo f: foos) {
        em.merge(f); // This works too
    }

    immediate.executeUpdate(); // Hang with no output!
    // Note: if I comment out above line the transaction may 
    // be silently rolled back on deferred constraint violation
}
```

Comment: Looks like Oracle 11gR1 and 11gR2 handle deferred constraints differently.  I've got R1 and am seeing the silent rollback behavior.  I've read an article describing a bug in R2, which indicates (1) a bug, and (2) R2 doesn't do a silent rollback:   http://www.pythian.com/news/9881/deferrable-constraints-in-oracle-11gr2-may-lead-to-logically-corrupted-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem can be in statement caching and in application server transaction strategy.

Try to:

- enforce entity manager to send data to database by calling em.flush() after for {} execution

and/or

- Change @TransactionManagement attribute to bean managed and manage transaction in your method

Comment: I ended up abandoning the set constraint statement approach, but using flushes or managing the transaction manually probably would work.  Not sure why or what changed, but now I'm getting an exception thrown at the end of the transaction when a deferred constraint is violated (which is what I wanted all along).  Maybe I had a caching issue?  Anyways, thanks for taking the time to answer my question.